# Let's talk about beefing up our help center

Tags: discussion, support

I've been looking at our Help Centre, especially the "[how to ask good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" page. Given that we direct new users to read it, shouldn't this be the very best it can?

I'd like to help expand the help center to be more detailed and informative.  I am possitive that between us we can add a few enhancements - if only with examples. How do we go about doing that?

Comment: Moderators can update the help section. If you want to rewrite an entire section then maybe making a meta post with the section as a title and rewrite as an answer so the community can critique it . Otherwise, text revisions can be posted as an answer below.

Comment: Additionally, it may be beneficial to join [The Loop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop) chat which is an open chatroom to answer any questions you have about the site.

Comment: We cannot edit the page "How do I ask a good question?".

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty, I think it already does what it's supposed to because most new users don't want to be told how to ask questions. What I will say is that it might be a good idea to throw community guidelines into that section for the sake of minimizing violations by any newcomers because after a certain point the info in the help centre becomes redundant & that's when people begin to skim & miss the important things